# Sending ERC20 tokens using web.py

Tags: erc-20, dapps, web3.py, defi, compound-protocol

I'm exploring blockchain development newly. I'm trying to explore how to send ERC20 token from my wallet to compound protocol. To be specific, I'm having a Metamask wallet with my private key, and I want to supply cUSDC token using Ropsten Network using web3.py. Have been trying this tutorial https://consensys.net/blog/developers/how-to-send-money-using-python-a-web3-py-tutorial/ and I'm stuck at this step where  `contract.functions.transfer('some account address',....).transaction(....)`, I'm not sure what should I put in transfer account address for supplying it to compound. In web3.js they've mint() function to supply. How can I do the same in python?

P.S: As I'm very new into this, I might miss some necessary info. Please ask in comments if you feel like I'm missing any important information.